# VHDL LR shifter circular not updating

Tags: vhdl

I have my code here but when i run my TB i have the problem that my shifting does not work when i leave the left ='1'  and the clock has another rising edge.

the objective here is to make a left right parallel shifting register.
the register has to update on every rising edge of the clock.
when le is high it loads information, when left is high it should do a left circular shift. if right is high it should do right circular shift.

[table explaining function of register](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6ihi.png)
What do i do wrong?

```
---------------------------------------------------------
-- Description: 
--  An n-bit register (parallel in and out) with left and right shift
--  functionality (circular).
--
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------


library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if using
-- arithmetic functions with Signed or Unsigned values
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if instantiating
-- any Xilinx leaf cells in this code.
--library UNISIM;
--use UNISIM.VComponents.all;

entity lr_shift_par_load is
    generic(
        C_REG_WIDTH : natural := 8
    );
    port(
          reset : in  STD_LOGIC;
            clk : in  STD_LOGIC;
           left : in  STD_LOGIC;
          right : in  STD_LOGIC;
             le : in  STD_LOGIC;
         par_in : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(C_REG_WIDTH-1 downto 0);
        par_out : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(C_REG_WIDTH-1 downto 0)
    );
end lr_shift_par_load;

architecture Behavioral of lr_shift_par_load is

    signal reg_i : std_logic_vector(C_REG_WIDTH-1 downto 0) := (others=>'0');
begin

    -- TODO: Write a process that implements the correct behaviour for reg_i.
    --   This should be a good refresher of your knowledge of last year.
    process(clk,reset)
    begin
        if(reset = '1')then
            reg_i <= (others=>'0');
        end if;
        if(rising_edge(clk)) then
            if(le ='1') then
                -- load
                reg_i <= par_in;
            elsif(le ='0' and left ='1')then 
                -- shift left
                reg_i <= par_in(C_REG_WIDTH-2 downto 0) &  par_in(C_REG_WIDTH-1);
            elsif(le ='0' and left ='0'and right ='1')then
                -- shift right
                reg_i <= par_in(0) & par_in(C_REG_WIDTH-1 downto 1);
            elsif(le ='0' and left ='0'and right ='0')then
                --hold
                reg_i <= par_in;
            end if;
        end if;
     end process;

    par_out <= reg_i;

end Behavioral;
```

Comment: You have two ifs for the reset and clock. The clock should be an elsif otherwise the clock has priority over the reset and likely not synthesisable (or you get sim/simulation missmatch)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When shifting you use the input vector 'par_in'. You probably want to use the shift register itself: 'reg_i'.

Also your conditions are unnecessary complex.

```
 if(le ='1') then
    -- load
     reg_i <= par_in;
 elsif(le ='0' ... << Why are you testing for this? 
                      If "le" was not zero it would never get here 
                      but get handled in the first 'if'.
```

Same here:

```
(le ='0' and left ='0'and right ='1') then
```

`(le ='0' and left ='0'` is superflous.

Comment: `If "le" was not zero it would never get here` The term is *inherent priority* useful in synthesis as Tricky's comment on merging the two if statements (`if reset = '1' then ...elsif rising_edge(clk) then...`) recommends to support synthesis primitive mapping. If statement condition evaluation has inherent priority while redundant condition expressions are logically reduced as Oldfart advocates doing manually  -  which can reduce simulation and synthesis execution time. Conditions need not be enclosed in parentheses they are syntactically distinct in VHDL.